# $f \in C^1[0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac {xf(x)}{f'(x)}=2$ ; then for $s<2$ ; $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{-s}f(x)=\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f \in C^1[0,\infty)$ be such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac {xf(x)}{f'(x)}=2$ ; then is it true that for $s<2$ , $x^{-s}f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $\frac{xf}{f'}\to2$, then there is some $M$ where $x>M\implies \frac{xf}{f'}<3$.

Then if $x>M$,

$$\int_M^x\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}dt>\int_M^x\frac{t}{3}dt\implies  \log\frac{f(x)}{f(M)}>\frac{x^2-M^2}{6}\implies f(x)>f(M)\exp\left(\frac{x^2-M^2}{6}\right)$$

Noting that $\exp\left(\frac{x^2-M^2}{6}\right)$ grows faster than any power of $x$, the result is proved. Note further that we do not need the $s<2$ stipulation for this to hold.

**[below - proof based on a misreading of the OP]**

If $\frac{xf'}{f}\to2>s$, then there is some $M$ where $x>M\implies \frac{xf'}{f}>\frac{s+2}{2}$.

Then if $x>M$,

$$\int_M^x\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}dt>\int_M^x\frac{s+2}{2}\frac{1}{t}dt\implies  \log\frac{f(x)}{f(M)}>\frac{s+2}{2}\log \frac{x}{M}$$

Then:

$$x^{-s}f(x)>x^{-s}f(M)\left(\frac{x}{M}\right)^{\frac{s+2}{2}}\propto x^{\frac{2-s}{2}}\to\infty$$

assuming $f(M)>0$. A similar result follows if $f(M)<0$

Comment: $\exists M >0 $ ... you should assume $M>0$ , otherwise you cannot divide by $x$ and retain inequality ...

Comment: @user228169 $f$ is only defined for $x\ge0$, so I don't think this really gets in the way - $M$ isn't going to be 0, because $0=\frac{xf'}{f}>\frac{s+2}{2}>1$ can't happen. Besides, it's a tail inequality, i.e. if $M$ works, so does any $M'>M$.

Comment: @πr8 The question is about $xf/f'$, not $xf'/f$.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini My mistake - have edited to fix. Misread because the $s<2$ condition is only material for the $xf'/f$ case.